# Amazon S3 all files work except .json | Getting cors error

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am using amazon s3 + cloudfront to save files.

I am requesting files from localhost (angular). For the first time ever I have a cors error. All other files, even those, which I added along with the .json file work fine.

The cors error is only for the .json file:

```
Access to fetch ... from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Why only .json triggers this error? The permissions while I upload the files are same across all files.

I have already added CORS policy to my bucket, but the error remains:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
]
```

It shouldn't even be necessary to add this, or? What's so special about .json files compared to .png, .css, .js etc.?

Where do I search for a solution? Maybe it does not have anything to do with S3 configurations?

Comment: Does it happen with all JSON files, or just one? Also see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/) if you haven't.